# Linux memory allocation on Rstudio/Rstudio Server

Tags: linux, cluster-analysis, rstudio-server

I am trying to do clustering with CLARA using Rstudio on Linux and I have a very large dataset.

However, it seemed that the memory is not enough for the whole dataset?

```
## Estimating the number of clusters ----
fviz_nbclust(df, clara, method = "silhouette", k.max = 15)
```

It showed me this:

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 339.8 GB

So I tried all of this and it still didn't work. memory.limit is also specific for Windows only (I still gave it a try tho).

```
# devtools::install_github("krlmlr/ulimit")
# gc() 
# memory.limit(9999999999)
# 
# 
# install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE)
# devtools::install_github("krlmlr/ulimit")
# ulimit::memory_limit(2000)
# 
# devtools::install_github("jeroen/unix")
# 
# 
# if(.Platform$OS.type == "windows") withAutoprint({
#   memory.size()
#   memory.size(TRUE)
#   memory.limit()
# })
# memory.limit(size=56000)
# memory.size(max = FALSE)
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means that it cannot allocate 339.8 GB to your RAM. Do you have 360GB of RAM?

If not, you will just have to `dplyr::nsample()` and just run the function on a subset of your dataset.